# req.params undefined when trying to find something in postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hey I'm making reset password route (EXPRESSJS) and I have a problem. My route looks like this: `/reset-password/:resetToken`.

And I get it like that: `const token = req.params.resetToken`

When I console.log that variable it logs it without any errors but when I try to check if it is in db it return as `undefined`

Some code:

```js
AuthRouter.put("/reset-password/:resetToken", async (req, res) => {
  const token = req.params.resetToken

 try {

    console.log(token);
    const getResetToken = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_password_reset_token = $1", [
      token
    ])
```

Comment: Does it work if you hard-code a known token?

Comment: try with `$1::text`

Comment: @Barmar when i make a variable and put it in the string it finds it in db

Comment: @cmgchess not working

Comment: @Luc Don't put it in the string. Use the same code but just with `const token = "XXX"` where `XXX` is the token.

Comment: @Barmar yeah i did it and it works but when i try to get it from url it doesnt work idk why

Comment: Try using `req.params.resetToken.strip()`. There may be extra whitespace around the parameter.

Comment: @Barmar it says it is not a function

Comment: Sorry, I meant `trim()` (strip is python)

Comment: Returns undefined idk what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Try add `` instead of " in query

```
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_password_reset_token = $1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this one, It will work on dynamic values:

```js
const getResetToken = await pool.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_password_reset_token = $1`,
    [token]
)
```